# Which Stripe api key should be used for unit tests

Tags: testing, stripe-payments

**A bit of context:** I started implementing payment in my project using Stripe, and I started thinking about how to write the tests. After learning a bit about how it should be done and having into account the "don't mock what you don't own" philosophy, I decided to implement a wrapper for stripe API and I now have two kinds of tests: Tests for my application mocking the API wrapper, and tests for the API wrapper (which I don't run as often as the ones for my app). This second tests call stripe for real, so I need to provide a Stripe API Key. And here's where my question comes in.

**Question:** Should I use my account's test api key for unit testing, or can I use a generic Stripe API key? Being them unit tests, I don't want them to leave any persistent logs to my account, not even on the test dashboard.

Searching in google I found the following api key: *tGN0bIwXnHdwOa85VABjPdSn8nWY7G7I* and unlike the test api key from my account, it doesn't follow the pattern "pk_test_*", but it does work with stripe and returns correct responses. If you are wondering where did I get that key (and if I should be publishing it), it has been officially published by stripe in [blog posts](https://stripe.com/blog/official-go-support) as well as [repositories](https://github.com/stripe/monospace-rails/blob/master/config/initializers/stripe.rb), but I couldn't find any explanation in the documentation or anywhere else, hence this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old Stripe API keys did not follow the `[sk|pk]_[test|live]_...` pattern. This is such a key.

Honestly though, I would recommend using either your own test API keys, or creating a different account (you can do so with the same email address: https://stripe.com/blog/manage-multiple-accounts). If a test fails, being able to see the log entry in the dashboard will probably be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can then assume that this api key belongs to some account and it isn't some "special key"? I understand that I should use my own test api key, but since I will probably execute this unit tests a lot, I would prefer not to clutter my account with this. I guess creating another account for this purpose would be a solution, but I think it's a bit overkill. I guess that's what I'll end up doing if I don't find any other solution.